# How do you change a single word in an EditText or any TextView without refreshing the whole variable?

Tags: java, android

I have a string like:

```
String testVar="this is a text with word Hello";
```

When I print it out:

```
editText.setText(testVar)
```

It gives the following output that the user can see:

> this is a text with word Hello

I need the program to change the word "Hello" to "Goodbye" when the user clicks on "Hello".
How do I accomplish this without doing the setText again (because setText will refresh the whole view which would take some time if testVar is long)?

I was thinking of making a subclass of EditText but I don't know where to start.

Also, is there a way to know how many system resources a function uses in Android programming? (sorry for the noob question but I can't find the answer on google)

Comment: When you say _"(because setText will refresh the whole view which would take some time if testVar is long)"_.. is this your opinion or have you performed any measurements? IMO the performance improvement will be minimal as even if you change a part of the string, the whole view will be re-drawn.

Comment: it is my opinion... it just feels slow when refreshing a TextView with a lot of text in it. I would be interested to know how exactly to prove this though

Answer (score 0):

use [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) in android to set clickable to your text.

```
SpannableString link = makeLinkSpan("Hello", new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // respond to click

        }
```

Comment: Does this avoid the use of setText? (the original OP question)